# Microsoft Excel Fuzzy Lookup add-on - set too big?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, comparison, duplicate, lookup

The data I'm comparing is a set of cataloged items (90k items) with an old list of items we thought were missing (about 11k). I need to see if any of the "missing" items actually show up in the cataloged set. I attempted to find duplicates using conditional formatting, but the main identifiers (call numbers) are too messy. 
for example

"Y 4 Ex 7/11:W 19/2/v.1-3" is in the cataloged set.

and 
Y 4.EX 7/11:W 19/2/V.1

Y 4.EX 7/11:W 19/2/V.2

Y 4.EX 7/11:W 19/2/V.3 are values in the missing set.

I am using fuzzy lookup to find near duplicates. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011
Per the instructions for using the fuzzy lookup add-in, I created two tables in separate tabs/worksheets, "cataloged_subsetA" and "missing_items". Then I set number of matches to 1 and similarity threshold to 0.85. I get to just over 4,700 rows compared and the program stops responding. I checked the memory usage and suspect that I am hitting memory threshold, but do not get error messages or anything saying that.

The results of the fuzzy lookup comparison should populate a blank sheet (or table) with the columns from "Cataloged_subsetA" and the columns from "missing_items" and a new column "similarity" with a value between 0 and 1

I have tried setting the configuration to "UseApproximateIndexing" - True. I have tried creating a table for the output; I tried using a blank worksheet. My tables only contain the rows with data, not an endless column. I don't have any null or empty cells in either table. I also tried using the smaller table as the "left table" and the larger table as the"right table" and vice versa. I uninstalled and re-installed the Fuzzy Matching Add-in.

I tried creating a subset of 30,000 rows (call numbers A-E), compared it to the set of 11,000, and got the same results: not responding after about 4700 rows completed. I then winnowed it down even further, a set of 12,000 to a set of 11,000. Same result.

Given the lack of transparency by Microsoft regarding the code of this add-in and the many unanswered questions on other community sites, I suspect I may need to give up on the add-in and find another way to compare these sets.

[Sample "cataloged_subsetA"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmB9h.png)
[Sample "missing_items"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAdHo.png)
[Sample desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GftKU.png)

Comment: I suggest you supply some sample data and a desired result. Then I suggest you tell us a bit more about what you have tried and what is not working. Then you will get help.

Comment: I don't seem to get the 1st sentence...the "comparing a table.. to get a table.. " , it seem doesn't pair up to the "need to see if any of the "missing" items actually show up in the cataloged set".. part.. || what is the formulae used? || I also couldn't reproduce the "tables that have 3 rows with ones that have 9 rows" that you mentioned that "works fine using your fuzzy lookup parameters".. would you mind walk us through with a small dummy data n a demo fuzzy search?

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose  I have attempted to clarify my question and provided sample data. Thanks for your feedback.